# What are the differences between these Swissstop rim brake pads?

Tags: brakes, rim-brake, brake-pads

What are the differences between the Swissstop Flash Pro [Power Black and BXP](https://www.tredz.co.uk/.Swissstop-Flash-Pro-Brake-Pads-Shimano-Fit_50567.htm) pads?

Also, which one is good for me? I only ride in dry weather unless it rains when it's dry.

Answer (score 2):

Swissstop have a web page that gives details of their different pad compounds: https://www.swissstop.ch/tech/compounds/

BXP has better performance than Original Black, but is more abrasive on your rims.

Comment: For what it's worth, i've been using Original black for years and am happy with the performance but i'm also very light.  A heavier rider might prefer the more powerful compound.

Answer (score 2):

The blue (BXP) rim brake pads have much better performance in wet conditions. The black pads are fine in dry conditions.

They used to have green ones which performed similar to the blue ones.

Comment: According to Swissstop the blue (BXP) outperforms the green (GHPII) compound in every way and hence replaced it.